# Create a container from vm

Tags: containers, dockerfile

I have a vm running on VMWARE ESXi. We launch it using ovf file using Vcenter
I want to create a container using same ovf and vmdk file. Is there a way

Comment: Containers and VMs are two *very* different things.

Comment: No it is impossible